# Probabilistic approach puzzle

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, probability-theory

A few hours earlier, I got this puzzle:

> Suppose, you toss a coin n times, then what is the probability of getting m number of heads? ( where m belongs to the *set of all prime numbers*)

For instance, take n = 2, then
`SS = { HH, HT, TH, TT }`

So, output is 1/4 (for HH case)

Then, for n = 3,
`SS = { HHH, HHT, HTH, THH, HTT, THT, TTH, TTT }`

So, output is (1 + 3)/8 (for 3 H's case and 2 H's cases respectively)

**Input**: n ( an integer, 0 <= n <= 1000 )
**Output**: The probability (in any distinguishable form, i.e., decimal, exponential, fraction, etc)

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes would win!

Comment: When you say n<1000 you mean that we should get results or the code can run forever?

Comment: @J42161217, it depends on you. n < 1000 is just a range of input for n (0 <= n < 1000).

Comment: ...the wording "where *m* is the set of all prime numbers" is a bit confusing, since you can't exactly have a number of heads equal to the set of all prime numbers (unless you're using an encoding of natural numbers into sets, in which case you should probably supply it!). I assume you actually mean that *m* is any prime number, although that wording suggests that you can pick a single one--it would be clearest to just not name it as a variable at all, and ask "in *n* flips of a fair coin, how likely are you to get a prime number of heads?"

Answer (score 9):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

Uses Binomial and outputs ,really fast, fractions

[image]

```
Tr@Binomial[#,Prime@Range@#]/2^#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6TIwSkzLz83MzEnWlknoCgzN9UhKDEvPdVBOVbfKE5Z7T9QLK9EwSE92jiWC8yOhtJgMQOsgthEDQ2Awv//AwA)

The original code according to my formula was

```
Tr@Binomial[#,Prime@Range@PrimePi@#]/2^#&
```

but, as **@attinat** commented, instead of searching all Primes < `n`  we can
search the first `n` primes because every prime > `n` returns zero binomial.
In this way we save *8 bytes*

Here is also the graph of the first 1000 cases which looks pretty cool

[image]

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6TIwSkzLz83MzEnWlknoCgzN9UhKDEvPdVBOVbfKE5Z7T9QLK9EwSE92jiWC8yOhtJgMQOsgthEDQ2Awv//AwA): `Binomial[n,k]`==0 if `n<k`

Comment: @attinat very nice! I'll edit

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
cÆRSH⁸¡
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/5cFtQsMejxh2HFv7//98YAA)**

#### How?

```
cÆRSH⁸¡ - Link@ integer, n                   e.g. 20
 ÆR     - primes to n                             [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
c       - (n) choose (vectorises)                 [190,1140,15504,77520,167960,77520,1140,20]
   S    - sum                                     340994
      ¡ - repeat...
     ⁸  - ...times: chain's left argument, n
    H   - ...action: halve
        -   (170497, 85248.5, ..., ~0.65, ~0.325) 0.3251972198486328
```

Comment: oh how I wish there were an `x/2^y` atom that doesn't floor like æ» (actually this inspired me to make a [pull request for one](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/pull/86) :))

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
ÅPcOso/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGtAsn9xvv7//2YA)

**Explanation**

```
ÅP       # push a list of primes upto and including input
  c      # push choose(input, prime) for each prime
   O     # sum
    so   # push 2^input
      /  # divide
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/MATLAB  with Statistics Package/Toolbox, 32 bytes

```matlab
@(n)sum(binopdf(primes(n),n,.5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0@zuDRXIykzL78gJU2joCgzN7UYKKiTp6Nnqqn5P03D2EDzPwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>198</s> <s>125</s> 97 bytes

```python
lambda n:f(n)/2**n
f=lambda n,h=0:h>1>sum(h%i<1for i in range(2,h))if n<1else f(n-1,h+1)+f(n-1,h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoIwEEB3v@IWQw9K9DBhaGi/xKXG1rsEDgI4@PXVQRe3l5e8t7x2nvVS2F/LGKfbPYK6bBRPXV3rIfuftOzPjgOF7TkZPspAeV5BQBTWqI9kOsuIkkEHSuOW4DNpyXJD2HwRy19CPbplFd2N2KoNlWUjiOUN)

To aid in understanding, I first generate all the of the possible combinations, then I get then total heads if that is prime, then I add the total number of primes.  The second function, `h` generates the result from function `f`.  Bellow is the original algorithm before minimizing it.

```python
def f(n,h=""):
  count = 0
  if n==0:
    hCount=h.count("h")
    for i in range(2, hCount):
      if hCount % i == 0:
        return 0
    if hCount < 2:
      return 0
    return 1
  count += f(n-1,h+"h")
  count += f(n-1,h+"t")
  return count

def h(n):
  return f(n), (2**n)

print(h(4))
```

Credits:

- From 125 to 97 bytes by [attinat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/attinat)

Comment: [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoIwEEB3v@IWQw9K9DBhaGi/xKXG1rsEDgI4@PXVQRe3l5e8t7x2nvVS2F/LGKfbPYK6bBRPXV3rIfuftOzPjgOF7TkZPspAeV5BQBTWqI9kOsuIkkEHSuOW4DNpyXJD2HwRy19CPbplFd2N2KoNlWUjiOUN): `sum(1for i in ... if c(i))==sum(c(i)for i in ...)`, apply De Morgan's Law and combine inequalities

Answer (score 2):

## Excel Formula, <s>311</s> 309 bytes

The following should be entered as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(IFERROR(COMBIN(A1,SMALL(IF(MMULT(--(IF(ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&A1))>TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&A1))),MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&A1)),(ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&A1))>TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&A1))))*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&A1)))))=0),ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&A1)))=0,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&A1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&A1)))),0))/(2^A1)
```

Where `A1` is the number to test.

**Examples:**

```
A1=15
Result: 0.34997558593750
A1=25
Result: 0.341329127550125
```

**Credits**

`-2` thanks to [Sophia Lechner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78915/sophia-lechner)!

Comment: Good to see someone else using Excel! Save two bytes per use by replacing `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&A1))` with `ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,A1))`

Comment: @SophiaLechner Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>12</s> 8 bytes

```
:ṅK¦Σ@z÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3@rhzlbvQ8vOLXaoOrz9/38TAA)

```
:		| dup input n
 ṅ		| push first n prime numbers, [2..k]
  K¦		| push n choose k (0 if k > n)
    Σ		| sum
     @z		| push 2^n
       ÷	| divide
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 35 bytes

```
n->binomial(n)*isprime([0..n])~/2^n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYtBCoAgEAC/snTSUNPu@ZEoMMhYyFWsc1/f9jKHYaaljvZqnGEBJhsPpFow3Yr0iE/rWE61eudo098078S5dkUSBwPBG5CCXhED2CjI8mnNPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 41 bytes

```
K`
"$+"+%`^
$"H
*\Cm`^(?!(..+)\1+$)..
m`^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zuBS0lFW0lbNSGOS0XJg0srxjk3IU7DXlFDT09bM8ZQW0VTT48LKPT/vzEA) Output is as a ratio. Explanation:

```
K`
"$+"+%`^
$"H
```

Generate all the possible coin tosses of `n` coins, but keep only the heads. (`T$"H` would keep the tails as well.)

```
*\Cm`^(?!(..+)\1+$)..
```

Count how many are prime and print on a separate line.

```
m`^
```

Count how many there are altogether.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 71 bytes

```javascript
n=>(s=1,g=i=>i<n&&(s*=(n-i)/++i)*(p=d=>i%--d?p(d):d==1)(i)+g(i))``/2**n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDoMwDEDRnVN4KbITUgojYHoVECEoFXIiUnWpevY0y3/Df62fNW2Xj28jwe7ZcRaeMXHXHOx59pPUNSbFKMZTq7UnhZFtOTdj7DOipcEyd4Se9FFCy9L2Skl24UIBhm4EgQn6R1Frgm8FsAVJ4dzvZzhQGnAoRGP1y38)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ø.ṗ§ẒÆm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9qZWxsef//w5gu4bmXwqfhupLDhm3///8z)

Different approach from Jonathan Allan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 13 bytes

```
õÈj *UàX /2pU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9chqICpV4FggLzJwVQ&input=OA)